# Copying .bitcoin to another system

Tags: blockchain, bitcoind, bitcoin-core

I already have a bitcoin node running over the network. Now my question is whether copying .bitcoin to another system will make a new node on that system or not?

I have seen some post where people have faced issues in doing so. If it is possible then what is the way to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. You can just copy the whole blockchain to default location i.e. /home/user_name/.bitcoin and run bitcoind and that's it. Your system will hardly take 3 4 minutes to verify and then your system will run as a full node.